# Writing Content Between Firefox Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, document

I am trying to write some values that I extract from a page (via JS/JQuery) opened in a tab in Firefox, to another opened page in a different tab within Firefox.  Is this possible?  Basically, I am trying to write some values I extract to a Google document that I have open in a different tab.  I can see the "document" value in the DOM for my Google Document is something like:

```
Doc?docid=0AQyS4r3XWCQ7ZGZ3dnE2OHNfMTNmcHE2OHAzMg&hl=en
```

Can I just write to that document?

Comment: More info what exactly you are trying to do are needed. At the moment this sounds more like a malicious data stealing attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Tabs normally can't do something like that (for security reasons).  You *might* be able to pull something like that off using bookmarklets, greasemonkey, or jetpack, but I don't know for sure.